# Javascript: meaning of the event and function separated by OR Operator

Tags: javascript

I found a block of code in a javascript. The event and function is separated with OR operator.

```
    var t = document.onmouseup || function () {};
```

Please help me to understand the above line.

Comment: It sets `t` to `onmouseup` if it's defined and not `null` or `false`, otherwise it sets it to an empty function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is to make sure that, `t` has a valid function, for the rest of the code.

It means that, if the `document.onmouseup` is already defined, assign it to `t`, otherwise assign the dummy function `function() {};` to `t`. So that, later on I can do `t()` without worrying whether `t` is a function or not.

The code takes advantage of the [`shortcircuit evaluation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) of JavaScript's logical operators.

But I believe, this is not foolproof enough. I would use

```
var t = typeof document.onmouseup === "function" ? document.onmouseup : function () {};
```

The difference between both the codes is that, the code in question just makes sure that `document.onmouseup` has a [`truthy value`](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/javascript-conventions/what-are-truthy-and-falsy-values) or not. But the code proposed in this answer makes sure that the type of `document.onmouseup` is a function.

Check this program to understand, why the code in question might fail.

```
function func1() {
    return 1;
}
var t = func1 || function() {};
console.log(t());
func1 = 1;
var t = func1 || function() {};
console.log(t());
```

**Output**

```
1
TypeError: number is not a function
```

Comment: @WebServer Would you please explain why not?

Comment: @WebServer Ya, you are correct... It takes `null`, if I assign it a number :) I removed that line from the answer. Do you know how it does that?

Comment: actually when you set <div onmouseup="1"></div> then its taken as
function(event){1},,why?? because whatever value we give to onmouseup should get executed on mouseup event firing.....But when you set HTMLElement.onmouseup = 1 via javascript
then it is not converted to function and is ignored by browser...

Answer (score 1):

This line means that the variable `t` shall take on the function of `document.mouseup` or if that's not defined, null or false use the anonymous `function() {}`.

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` operator returns its left argument if it's truthy, otherwise it returns its right argument.

So this sets `t` to the `mouseup` handler if it's set, otherwise it sets it to a function that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

it means

```
var t;
if ( document.onmouseup ) {
    t = document.onmouseup ;   
} else {
    t = function () {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code you found is a shorthand declaration, it is functionally equal to the following:

```
if(document.onmouseup)
{
    var t=document.onmouseup;
}
else
{
    var t=function(){};
}
```

shorthand declarations are one of the things that make javascript the powerful and usefull language it is (and the reason its one of the few languages that doesnt have `elseif`)

Shorthand declarations are always shorter, and in some cases actually improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

consider expression ( A || B )
then its evalutation is :

```
if !!A is true then evaluate to A
else evaluate to B
```

So when you write

```
var t = A || B
```

then if !!A evaluates to true then value of t will be A
else value of t will be B

Here in your example A is document.onmouseup and B is function () {}

so if document.onmouseup exists then !!document.onmouseup will be true and t will be assigned to it,
else t will be assigned to function(){}